# Migration Auth laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

Why after creating a new project on larawer every time i try to refresh the migration in the console i see it

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>         SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 byt
>         es (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))
>
> [PDOException]
>         SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 byt
>         es

and next

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>         SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null
>          auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token`
>          varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
>
> [PDOException]
>         SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

When you create a new project you need to get rid of the migration that was created by make: auth ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved the problem, in the older version of MySql laraver in the file App / Providers / AppServiceProvider.php

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

Comment: If this solved your question you can still mark this as the answer with the checkmark to the left (even if it is your answer on your own question)